# Process of adding an index to production db

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table with 1M rows and I need to add an index on it. What would be the process of doing so? Am I able to do `ALTER TABLE table ADD INDEX column (column)` directly on production? Or do I need to take other things into account to add the index.

How does one normally go about adding an index on a live production db?

Comment: You wait until people aren't using the database, then do it.  Such as overnight.  Or you get *very* involved so as to slowly create a replacement for the old table while maintaining both (triggers, etc), then deleting the old table and renaming the new table.

Comment: @Dems what do you mean by 'very involved'? Do you mean attend to closely? Or involve a lot of planning and programming?

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename\G` and display that in the Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first try adding the same index on your test database under similar load conditions and check that it doesn't cause problems. It's possible that by creating the index you lock the table for some time and cause other queries to fail.

One million rows is a large table, but it's not huge. You will probably find that the adding the index completes reasonably quickly. Unless you have real-time constraints it's unlikely to cause serious issues. It's definitely worth testing it first though.

Comment: Thanks, how would I go about simulating 'similar load conditions' on the test database?

Comment: @David542: Could you wait until there is no load? That is the easiest to simulate.

Comment: Yeah, that would make most sense.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd wait until things were quiet, but you don't have to take the database offline. Users might see a delay, but it shouldn't time out. (If it does, something else is wrong.)

Note that adding an index doesn't make the dbms copy the whole table (as adding a column might).